# implement sum aggregator on custom case class on spark sql dataframe (UDAF)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a case class

```
case class Vec(var a: Int, var b: Int) {
    def +(v: Vec): Vec = {
        a += v.a
        b += v.b
        this
    }
}
```

Now if I write

```
val rDistDS: RDD[(Int, Vec)] = ...
val sums: RDD[(Int, Vec)] = rDistDS.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

I get the sum of all the vectors associated with each `Int` key. Excellent.

However, I'd like to do this with a `DataFrame` to potentially help the query planner and make the code more readable.

I would like to be able to do the following

```
val df: DataFrame = ... // each row has Row(theInt: Int, vec: Vec)
df.groupBy(df("theInt")).agg(sum(df("vec")))
```

Is there a way to implement this `sum` aggregator on my custom `case class` for use with the Spark SQL Dataframe as simulated above?

As it stands I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType$ cannot be cast to 
        org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$Cast$$cast(Cast.scala:429)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Spark 1.4, I don't think UDAF are supported.

Please have a look at the following tickets for more information:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3947
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4233
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6802